# Laravel test case tests redirect to a certain route

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, laravel-5, phpunit

I'm writing some test cases for my Laravel app with PHPUnit.

Below is the class that is producing the error:

```
<?php

namespace Test\Feature;

use Tests\TestCase;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;

class UserLoginTest extends TestCase
{
    use DatabaseMigrations;

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->admin = factory(User::class)->create([
                'is_admin'  => true,
                'password'  => bcrypt('secret'),
            ]);
    }

    /** @test */
    public function test_login_user_form()
    {
        $this->get('/login')
            ->assertStatus(200);
    }

    /** @test */
    public function test_login_user_form_submission()
    {
        $this->post('/login', [
                'email'     => $this->admin->email,
                'password'  => 'secret',
            ]);

        $this->assertRedirectedTo('/');
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I run PHPUnit I get this error:

> PHPUnit 5.7.20 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
>   ....E..                                                             7
>   / 7 (100%)
>   Time: 1.65 seconds, Memory: 20.00MB
>   There was 1 error:
>   1) Test\Feature\UserLoginTest::test_login_user_form_submission Error:
>   Call to undefined method
>   Test\Feature\UserLoginTest::assertRedirectedTo()
>   /Users/shivampaw/Desktop/valet/UltimateCRM/tests/Feature/UserLoginTest.php:37

It says that `assertRedirectedTo` is an undefined method but I do not have any clue why. I have tried methods like `assertRedirect` but cannot get this working!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to call `assertRedirect` and not `assertRedirectedTo`. Also all assertions need to be called on the `response` object

```
/** @test */
public function test_login_user_form_submission()
{
    $this->post('/login', [
        'email'     => $this->admin->email,
        'password'  => 'secret',
    ])->assertRedirect('/'); // <-- Chain it to the response
}
```

Comment: What if I wanted to assertRedirectRoute?

Comment: @Shiv there is no such method, but you could use the `route()` helper function, something like: `assertRedirect(route('some_route'))`